# How to substring this String

Tags: java, android, substring

I want to get 4 parts of this string

```java
String string = "10 trillion 896 billion 45 million 56873";
```

The 4 parts I need are "10 trillion" "896 billion" "45 million" and "56873".

What I did was to remove all spaces and then substring it, but I get confused about the indexes.
I saw many questions but could not understand my problem.

```java
Sorry I don't have any code
```

I couldn't run because I didn't know that was right.

Comment: try regex pattern

Comment: "What I did was to remove all spaces and then substring it" - so you do have some code. Please include that code, or at least a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need regular expression and pattern matcher .find methods with grouping, but sorry I don't have the code ;)

Comment: Tag questions properly ..it aint an `android` related question

Comment: I think it was because I was doing it on android studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will work. Check comments for added instructions.

```
String input = "10 trillion 896 billion 45 million 56873";
        String pattern = "\\s\\d";     // this will match space and number thus will give you start of each number.
        ArrayList<Integer> inds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            inds.add(m.start());          //start will return starting index.
        }

        //iterate over start indexes and each entry in inds array list will be the end index of substring. 
        //start index will be 0 and for subsequent iterations it will be end index + 1th position.
        int indx = 0;
        for(int i=0; i <= inds.size(); i++) {
            if(i < inds.size()) {
                strs.add(input.substring(indx, inds.get(i)));    
                indx = inds.get(i)+1;
            } else {
                strs.add(input.substring(indx, input.length()));
            }
        }

        for(int i =0; i < strs.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(strs.get(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex:

```
\d+(?: (?:tri|bi|mi)llion)?
```

It first matches a bunch of digits `\d+`, and then optionally `(?:...)?`, we match either trillion, billion, or million `(?:tri|bi|mi)llion`.

[image]

To use this regex,

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?: (?:tri|bi|mi)llion)?").matcher(string);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Please tell what this regex means

Comment: I have added an image visualising it, in addition to the text explaining it written just after the regex. What parts do you not understand? @DemonAppProgrammer

Comment: That pictured helped me understand, Thanks

Comment: I am making my coding correct, If I get the desired result, I would accept that answer

Answer (score 4):

> **This is a way to get your solution easily.**

```
String filename = "10 trillion 896 billion 45 million 56873";
String regex = " [0-9]";
    
String[] values = filename.split(regex);
// You can get the value by position -> values[0] ... values[n]

// Use the Foreach loop to get all the values.
for(String subValue: values ){
    Log.i(TAG, "Part : "+subValue);
}
```

Comment: Please Tell what this regex means?And what is split() function

Comment: I have set the " " (space) in the first position of the regex. and after I have written [0-9]. It means that wherever you get the value as "space with any number between 0 to 9" from the bunch of value.

Comment: You will get value from there after the spirit value.

Comment: that means I need to first replace the space (" ") with nothing("")?

Comment: please help that if I have "34 million 34879"(this excludes billion and trillion) as a string.Then part1 = 34 million ?

Comment: Yes, It will work the same as you think. "34 million 34879" first part have set "34 million" and second part have set "34879",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194577/discussion-between-prince-and-demon-app-programmer).

Answer (score 1):

Regex is the answer

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(\\d+\\s+\\w+)|\\d+";
final String string = "10 trillion 896 billion 45 million 56873";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

It will print

Full match: 10 trillion

Group 1: 10 trillion

Full match: 896 billion

Group 1: 896 billion

Full match: 45 million

Group 1: 45 million

Full match: 56873

Group 1: null

[image]

Comment: Please tell what this regex means

Comment: @DemonAppProgrammer check here [regex means](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/regex.htm) and this https://regexr.com/

Comment: It tries to match #number#space#word , this basically covers your input string , the left out part is matched by \\d+ (which matches a number ).

Comment: You can try out different regex here https://regex101.com/ with your input string. It has an auto code generation feature too. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Regex expression:

```
String string = "10 trillion 896 billion 45 million 56873";
String[] array = string.split("(?<!\\G\\w+)\\s");
```

Essentially, we're splitting on every second space rather than on every space.

Comment: What does this regex means

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern.

> ```
> ([^\s]+\s+[^\s]+|[^\s]+)
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try the below code.

public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "10 trillion 896 billion 45 million 56873 ";

```
    String[] strlist = str.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < strlist.length; i++) {
        String data=textNumber(strlist[i], (i+1<strlist.length?strlist[i + 1]:""));
        if (data != null) {
            System.out.println(data);
            i++;
        }
    }

}
public static String textNumber(String str1,String str2){

    if(str1.matches("[0-9]+")){
        if(str2.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
            return  str1 + " " + str2;
        }
        return str1;
    }
     return null;
}
```