# How to replace every whitespace between 2 numbers?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I am making a program to get the different parts of a string like "10 trillion 837 billion 45 million 56739".I asked this Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56488486/how-to-substring-this-string).
But sometimes my string gets like "10 trillion 837 billion 45 million 56 739".
I want to remove whitespace between 6 and 7 in "56 739".

I know to remove a whitespace but don't know how to specify between which characters would be the whitespace to remove

This is my code

```java
String input = "10 trillion 837 billion 45 million 56 739";
                String pattern = "\\s\\d";     // this will match space and number thus will give you start of each number.
                ArrayList<Integer> inds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
                Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
                Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
                while (m.find()) {
                    inds.add(m.start());          //start will return starting index.
                }

                //iterate over start indexes and each entry in inds array list will be the end index of substring.
                //start index will be 0 and for subsequent iterations it will be end index + 1th position.
                int indx = 0;
                for(int i=0; i <= inds.size(); i++) {
                    if(i < inds.size()) {
                        strs.add(input.substring(indx, inds.get(i)));
                        indx = inds.get(i)+1;
                    } else {
                        strs.add(input.substring(indx, input.length()));
                    }
                }

                for(int i =0; i < strs.size(); i++) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),strs.get(i)+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

I tried to add replaceAll statement like this`input = input.replaceAll("\\d\\s\\d","\\d\\d");` But it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I figured out (or assumed) is that you are trying to remove spaces between numbers in your `string` so,

You can use this `regex` to replace your `space` between the numbers:

`(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=\\d|\\-)` like:

```
input = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=\\d|\\-)", "");
```

`(?<=\d)` is a positive lookbehind, it checks if the previous symbol is a digit, without actually matching it.

`(?=\d)` is a positive lookahead, same thing - checks if the following symbol is a digit, without actually matching it.

You can test regex here:
https://regex101.com/r/pdEoKO/1/